# I received -15 points on a response I gave to a question - why is this? It hasn't been downvoted.

Tags: discussion, support

I received -15 points on a response I gave to a question, but the response wasn't downvoted once. I am unsure as to why I have been downvoted. Can anyone assist?

[View object fields and data](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/122284/view-object-fields-and-data/122293#122293) is the link. I can only assume that because I gave a link to a review of an App, that comes under 'cross promotion' or something. Regardless of the fact that the review is completely unbiased, I have been given -15 points. It's a bit disappointing.

Many thanks,
Andy

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A downvote subtracts 2 points. If you lost 15, the reason is likely to be different. Which your [reputation history](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/21018/andy-hitchings?tab=reputation) shows:

> Jun 6, 15:48   (-15) unaccept     View object fields and data

The author of the question originally marked your answer as accepted, which gave you 15 points. Then they changed their mind, selecting another answer. So those 15 points went away.

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Yes I saw it happen to me on an answer.

Comment: Happened to me as well, left me depressed for days :-(

Comment: I had something happen when a new user copied the gist of my answer then posted it as an answer to their question and changed the acceptance, which I felt was a bit off in taking credit away from the person supplying the answer.

Comment: @soup I will do now as I wasn't too bothered as it was a really simple answer and the user was new enough that I didn't want to push them out of the community over that.